# JS node, waiting for function to complete before executing second function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, synchronous

I am trying to execute `firstFunction()` which parses a csv file and  returns some data, and pass that to `secondFunction()` to then perform some operations. I've tested both independently and they both work as intended, but I can't get the `secondFunction()` to execute after `firstFunction()` is complete. This results in 'data' being undefined at time of execution.

```
function parentFunc(){
  firstFunction(function(data){
    secondFunction(data);
  });
}


function firstFunction(){
  var inputFile = 'import.csv';
  var dataOutput = [];
  var colHead = [];
  var parser = parse({delimiter: ','}, function(err, data){
    colHead.push(data[0][0],data[0][1],data[0][2],data[0][3],data[0][4]);
    for( i = 1; i<data.length; i ++ ){
      var line = {[colHead[0]]:data[i][0],
                  [colHead[1]]:data[i][1],
                  [colHead[2]]:data[i][2],
                  [colHead[3]]:data[i][3],
                  [colHead[4]]:data[i][4]};
      dataOutput.push(line);
    }

  });
  var readStream = fs.createReadStream(inputFile).pipe(parser);
  readStream.on('end', function(){
    return dataOutput;
  })
}
async function secondFunction(data){
  for(i=0; i<data.length;i++){
    //some operations with data, using await keyword.
  }
}

parentFunc();
```

I feel like the solution should not be that tough, and is probably due to a fundamental misunderstanding on my part.

Please let me know if more information is required.

Comment: It would probably be easier for us to see what the problem is if you included the code that you have written. Here we can't see how and when `data` gets populated.

Comment: Impossible to help you with the information provided. Need to know what is in these functions

Comment: @LucaKiebel Updated my question with requested information, thanks.

Comment: `firstFunction` does *not*  `return` anything. And while you tried to pass a callback when calling it, the function doesn't (yet?) have a callback parameter.

Comment: @Bergi Doesn't it return `dataOutput`? Can you show me what you mean by your second sentence?

Comment: @pjctech No, the `return dataOutput` is in the callback function for the `end` event. You should add a callback parameter, and then call the callback function on this event

Comment: @Bergi `firstFunction()` is returning my data, I can see that it does when I log it, so not sure what you mean but I accept that I may be missing something. The accepted answer is working for me, but I am curious as to other solutions.

Comment: @pjctech No, it doesn't return anything. It asynchronously logs it, nothing else. `console.log(firstFunction())` will produce `undefined`

Comment: @Bergi Thank you, I see that now! So how shall I get `firstFunction()` to `return dataOutput`?

Comment: @pjctech Seems you already did by making a promise for it, otherwise the accepted answer wouldn't work for you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return a `promise` from the firstFunction

```js
function sometestFunction() {
  return Math.random();
}

function secondFunction(data) {
  console.log('data received from first function ' + data)
}

function firstFunction() {
  return Promise.resolve(sometestFunction())
}

firstFunction().then(function(data) {
  secondFunction(data);
})
```

In your case the usage of `async` `await` seems to be wrong. An `await` always goes inside an `async`. So use `async` with parent function and `await` till the firstFucntion is resolved

```js
async function parentFunc() {
  let x = await firstFunction();
  secondFunction(x);
}



function firstFunction() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);
    }, 3000)
  })
}

function secondFunction(data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[i])
  }
}

parentFunc();
```

Comment: This works for me! I am not sure why the promise is required within `firstFunction()` but it seems `parentFunc()` is not abiding by async/await without it? I will definitely read more about this, but please let me know if I am off base or if you have any insight.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it happens is because parsing your `csv` file is an **asynchronous** action.

To make sure that your `secondFunction` will be executed after your `firstFunction`, you would need to use either promises or async/await.

Basically this is what it would look :

#### Using promises

```js
function parentFunc() {
  firstFunction().then(secondFunction)
}
```

#### Using async/await

```js
async function parentFunc() {
  let data = await firstFunction()
  secondFunction(data)
}
```

Here are some additional resources on promises and async/await :

- [Promises](https://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript-promises-for-dummies)
- [Async/Await](https://javascript.info/async-await)

Hope it helps!

Comment: The async await example you gave me is what I thought would work too, I've tried that previously. The error I get is: 
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`
I will try the solution using promises, but I was told by a mentor that promises are not common in node.

Comment: I tried the promise suggestion and am getting the same error.